# Linker error with Duplicated Symbols, SWIG and C++ Vectors

Tags: c++, linker, swig, stdvector, duplicate-symbol

I came across this error trying to compile a shared object from 2 sets of objects.  The first set contains one .os object compiled from one cpp file generated by SWIG.  The second set is contains all of the .so files from the individual files that make up the interface to be wrapped.

```
$g++ -shared *.os -o Mathlibmodule.so
ld: duplicate symbol std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::size() constin Mathlib_wrap.o and Capsule.o
```

The swig c++ wrapper (Mathlib_wrap.o's source file) is machine generated and nasty to look at, with lots of #defines to make it extra hard to trace.  It looks like the redefinition is present in all of the object files in the second set.  I've traced through the headers included in all those files, and the seem to be #pragma once'd.

What advice do people have for tracking down what/where the problem is?

Comment: Given the amount of info you could provide, I'd have to recommend you stop using swig.

Comment: Its a codebase I just inherited that I'm "porting" from cross platform libraries from MSVC to *nix + SCons.  I'm not very familiar with the code myself, so I was looking for more general advice like "such and such construct often causes these errors".  As for SWIG, I very much want to be able to script in python, so scrapping SWIG isn't an attractive option.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you've properly #ifndef/#define blocked all of the header files in your C++ library, after that I'd check your `.i` file to make sure you aren't actually duplicating some declaration there somehow. Maybe try importing a small small piece of the library first or something.

I *have* run into issues like this before, but its always turned out to be something silly I'd done. Nothing specific I'm afraid.

Post the .i file maybe, donno.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, assume that the error means what it says: Actual code was generated for `vector<T>::size` within each of those object files. This of course seems very unusual because you would expect the function to be expanded inline in each file it was being used in.

If it weren't `std::vector` the first thing I would say is that a function defined in a header wasn't marked inline correctly. The compiler would generate the code in each source file that included that header. What version of g++ are you using, and are you using a custom standard library/vector implementation?

One thing to check is to compile with optimization on (`-O2`) and see if that causes it to inline the calls within creating an actual function.

Another possibility is that you're including two different versions of the `vector` include, and violating the one definition rule. At that point I wouldn't rule out a linker error such as you're seeing.